# `npm install` fails with package-lock.json on node:10.21.0-jessie-slim Dockerimage

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, ssh, debian-jessie

I'm trying to npm install a project with `git+ssh://git@github.com` dependencies using node:10.21.0-jessie-slim docker image.

I'm running a ssh-keyscan like that:

```
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh \
  && ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Without the package-lock, I'm able to install the dependencies.
But when the package-lock exists, the authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.

I found that when I run with package-lock, the know_hosts file used is the one in `/home/node/.ssh/`

So, I add it on my Dockerfile:

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> /home/node/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And it works. But I want to know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your ssh config file set some properties true like `CheckHostIP` or `HashKnownHosts` so if any property set to true which force ssh to verify the host then ssh first look into known_hosts so verify you ssh config file.

```
 ~/. ssh/config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

please have a look https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/